# about the smallest normal subgroup containing some generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume $f:G\to K$ is a group homomorphism, and $S\subset G$ is a set of elements such that $f|_S$ is trivial. Denote by $N\leq G$ the smallest normal subgroup such that $S\subset N$. Is it obvious that $f$ is trivial on all of $N$?

Comment: Yes, it is obvious. Note that $N$ is certainly contained in $\ker f$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, you are not saying anything with that comment

Comment: @GuillermoMosse He's not saying anything except for explaining how to do the problem. In more detail: $N$ is the intersection of all the normal subgroups of $G$ containing $S$. So $N\subset\ker(f)$.

Comment: Isn't she just rephrasing the question? I see your point, anyway.

Comment: @GuillermoMosse Ok, it may be that the comment is "not saying anything", since I suppose it _is_ just a rephrasing of what needs to be proved. But the rephrasing makes it obvious why the problem is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Silly to give yet another answer for such a triviality, but none of the existing ones seem quite right.

By definition, $N$ is the intersection of the normal subgroups containing $S$. Since $\ker(f)$ is a normal subgroup and $S\subset\ker(f)$, this says that $N\subset\ker(f)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if it is "obvious" but the answer is yes.

Let $G_S$ be the subgroup generated by $S$. Let $N$ be the smallest normal subgroup containing $S$, and let $N_2$ be the smallest normal subgroup that is in ker$(f)$ that contains $S$--and there indeed is such an $N_2$ as $S \subseteq $ ker$(S)$, and ker$(f)$ is itself a normal subgroup of $G$.

Then $N \cap N_2$ is a normal subgroup as well (check to make sure you see why) and as both $N$ and $N_2$ each contain $S$, the subgroup $N \cap N_2$ also contains $S$. So for $N$ to indeed be the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ containing $S$ as defined, it follows that $N \cap N_2 = N$. But then this implies that $N \subseteq$ ker$(f)$ because $N_2 \subseteq$ ker$(f)$. Which is what you were trying to show.

Comment: Why so complicated? By definition $N$ is the intersecction of all the normal subgroups containing $S$. We're given that $S\subset\ker(f)$, and $\ker(f)$ is a normal subgroup. So $S\subset\ker(f)$. Done.

Comment: Very nice @DavidC.Ullrich.  You are correct. (I upvoted your comment). (That said, $N$ is indeed the intersection of all normal subgroups containing $S$ as the intersection of normal subgroups is itself a normal subgroup, but I don't know if it is "by definition") But yes I agree what you wrote is the answer.

Comment: If the definition is "the smallest..." that raises the question of why there _is_ a smallest one.

Answer (score -1):

Tip: show that $S$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, so that $S=N$.

(In fact this is equivalent to the exercise, right?)

Comment: ??? There's no reason $S$ should be a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: am I not understanding something? If $s, t \in S \Rightarrow f(st) = f(s) f(t) = 0$

Comment: Oh! $S$ is "**a**" set of element such that.... I read "**the**"

Comment: I figured the problem was there. Didn't want to presume to conjecture whether you misread the problem or didn't understand the difference (we do see problem statements here that read "a set of..." where "the set of..." was intended.)

Answer (score -1):

Let $N$ be the normal subgroup generated by $S$, the kernel of the restriction $f_{\mid N}$ is a normal subgroup which contains $S$, so it is $N$ sionce $S$ generates and $f_{\mid N}$ is trivial.

Comment: Why do you say "the kernel  of the restriction $f|N$"? That makes no sense until we know that $f:N\to N$. Seems to me that what you said is exactly right _if_ you change those words to "the kernel of $f$".